# Where to store Sublime Text 2 config file on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, config, sublimetext

I'm starting to use Sublime Text 2. I used this page http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/. As an addition I'm reading this guides:

http://www.nerdi.net/blog/2012/02/05/customize-your-sublime-text-2-configuration-for-awesome-coding/

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/search-and-replace.html

but can't find in them an answer to a simple question - where to store a config file (good examples by the way http://www.thenerdary.net/post/29338253893/my-sublime-text-2-config)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

or

```
Preferences -> Settings-User.
```

I was also advised to use this option

```
"save_on_focus_lost": true
```